# Update click event of moved DOM element

Tags: jquery

I have 2 unordered lists each in their own div.
If I click a list item in the first list I want it to move to the second. And vice-versa when double clicking in the second list.

Code:

```
$('.filelist > ul > li > a').click(function(){
    //
    // Clicked file in Filelist (list 1)
    //
    console.log('file in list');
    $(this).parent().appendTo('#queue-list');           
});
$('.queuelist > ul > li > a').dblclick(function(){
    //
    // Clicked file in Queue (list 2
    //
    console.log('file in queue');
    $(this).parent().appendTo('#file-list');
});
```

The first part works, list items are moved from list 1 to list 2.
But when I click (not doubleclick) in list 2 it still logs 'file in list', so the onclick function of the moved element is not updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you bind the handlers to the actual elements. So when you change thair DOM location they still maintain the same handler that was bound at the beginning..

You need to delegate the handling to the `ul` elements (*use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method*)

```
$('.filelist > ul').on('click',' > li > a', function(){
    //
    // Clicked file in Filelist (list 1)
    //
    console.log('file in list');
    $(this).parent().appendTo('#queue-list');           
});
$('.queuelist > ul').on('dblclick',' > li > a', function(){
    //
    // Clicked file in Queue (list 2
    //
    console.log('file in queue');
    $(this).parent().appendTo('#file-list');
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/XhD9H/

Comment: you are welcome.. If you look at the `click` documentation (http://api.jquery.com/click/) you will see that it is now a shortcut of `.on('click')`.. (*it was added in v1.7*)